# Assigning number to list of connected components in Networkx

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have created a graph using networkx:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)
list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

The output looks like this:

```
{'John Doe' , 'James Doe'},
{'Jack Fisher', 'Adam Scott', 'Jane Matters'}
```

I want to numerically group all the connected components together. So John Doe and James Doe are part of group 1 and then the next list is part of group 2.

I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: ultimately i want to turn it into a dataframe with the name and the group they belong to based on the output of the connected components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could quite easily build a dictionary enumerating the set of connected components with `enumerate`, and building a `dict` from the tuples:

```
s = {'John Doe' , 'James Doe'}, {'Jack Fisher', 'Adam Scott', 'Jane Matters'}

dict(enumerate(s))
# {0: {'James Doe', 'John Doe'},
#  1: {'Adam Scott', 'Jack Fisher', 'Jane Matters'}}
```

For a `pd.DataFrame`, you could use a dictionary comprehension as follows:

```
d = {name:k for k,comp in enumerate(s) for name in comp}
(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['component'])
   .rename_axis('name')
   .reset_index())

           name  component
0     James Doe          0
1      John Doe          0
2  Jane Matters          1
3    Adam Scott          1
4   Jack Fisher          1
```